# Adding a number to an event in a Sheet once a Form has submitted data to the Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script to add an "Incident" number to the Incident Number column (Column 1) when a form is submitted and the Data is added to the linked Google Sheet (Sheet Name "IIR") by detecting new data in Column 4. Row one contains the Sheet Headers (developed by the questions in the Form). I pilfered a script with the same intent from other sources, the Script runs with no errors but I am not getting the desired result to the sheet (I am a Newbee).

```
//CORE VARIABLES
// The column you want to check if something is entered.
enter code here var COLUMNTOCHECK = 4; // Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
var ADDNUMBER = [1,1]; // Sheet you are working on
var SHEETNAME = "IIR"

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("IIR"); //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
      if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
          var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell(); //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the number to appear.
          if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
              var IncidentNumber = selectedCell.offset(ADDNUMBER[1],ADDNUMBER[1]);
                  for (r=1; r<999; r++) {
                  ss.getRange(r,1).setValue(r);
          }
      }
}}
```

Comment: onEdit  won't work in this situation because it only responds to user edits.  Read the documentation on simple triggers.  You can try using onFormSubmit .

Answer (score 0):

**Append incident number to time stamp in linked sheet**

This function will add a incident number that is made up from the time stamp by using a two digit year followed by a two digit month followed by a two digit day and then a dash and then consecutive incrementing numbers.  It also keeps the timestamp and adds the incident number to the bottom of the cell.

```
function formSubmit(e) {
  if(e.values && e.values[1]) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    var sh=e.range.getSheet();
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(getIncidentNumber(e));
  }
}

function getIncidentNumber(e) {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var ts=e.values[0];
  var key=Utilities.formatString('%s%s%s',ts.slice(8,10),ts.slice(0,2),ts.slice(3,5));
  if(ps.keys && ps.getKeys().indexOf(key)==-1) {
    ps.setProperty(key,1);
    return key + "-" + 1;
  }else{
    var value=ps.getProperty(key);
    ps.setProperty(key, Number(value) + 1)
    var rv = ts + '\n' + key + "-" + Number(value).toFixed();
    return rv;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `Incident number` from the sheet you should open the **Script editor** from the **Form**. In this way, the script will be bound to the actual form.

Afterwards, you should be using the following script:

```js
var DESTINATION_SS_ID = "YOUR_DESTINATION_SHEET_ID";

function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var incidentNumber = e.response.getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DESTINATION_SS_ID);
  ss.appendRow([incidentNumber]);

}
```

The script is using an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and instead of going through the bounded sheet from the form, like you did, it takes the response **directly from the form** and adds it to your wanted spreadsheet. This is done by using the `onFormSubmit` installable trigger.

To install the trigger you should follow these steps:

- Go to your project's triggers by clicking this icon:

[image]

- Create a new trigger with the following settings:

[image]

- Save the project.

For the trigger to work, you/other users just have to **send responses through the form**. The results are obtained by using the `.getItemResponses()` method followed by the `.getResponse()` method, which essentially get you the responses you/other users have sent. Afterwards, these responses are added to the sheet by using the `.appendRow()` method; so every time a new entry gets submitted in the form, the `Incident number` is automatically added to your spreadsheet.

Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at these links since they might be of help in your future development:

1. [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
2. [Event objects - Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1);
3. [FormResponse Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response);
4. [ItemResponse Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response.html);
5. [Sheet Class - appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents).